# Time isnt correct but code seems to be correct :S (unexpected outcome)

Tags: c, pointers, time, arguments, clock

So im trying to build a program that tells u the exact time in years, days, hours and mins.

i have checked my code over and it seems to be okay and the outcomes are close to correct but aren't exactly correct, i have posted my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void year_day(time_t seconds, float *yearsLPtr, float *dayLPtr){
    int yearS;
    float t_constant;//seconds per year

    t_constant = 365.2425*24*60*60; //seconds in a year (years to 4dp)
    *yearsLPtr =(seconds/t_constant);// years as float since 1970 1/1 00:00
    yearS=*yearsLPtr; //sending float to int
    *dayLPtr = (((seconds/t_constant) - yearS)*365.2425);//used exact number for years to neglext error
    *yearsLPtr+=1970; //adding 1970 to change in years to get current year
}

void hours_minutes(float dayL, float *hoursLPtr, float *minsLPtr){
    float t_constant;
    int dayS, minS;
    dayS=dayL;
    t_constant= 365.2425*24*60*60;
    *hoursLPtr= (dayL-dayS)*24;
    minS= *hoursLPtr;
    *minsLPtr= (((dayL-dayS)*24)-minS)*60;


}

void print_time (float yearsL, float dayL, float hoursL, float minsL){

    int constant, yearsS, dayS, hoursS, minsS;

    yearsS=yearsL; //converting from float back to int, couldve pointed to int straight away tho
    dayS=dayL;
    hoursS=hoursL;
    minsS=minsL;

    printf("Year: %i \t", yearsS);
    printf("Day: %i \t",dayS);
    printf("Hour: %i \t",hoursS);
    printf("Min: %i \t",minsS);

}


int main() {

    float yearsL, dayL, hoursL, minsL;

    time_t current_seconds; //time t like long/double for longer values

    current_seconds=time(NULL);

    year_day(current_seconds,&yearsL,&dayL);
    hours_minutes(dayL,&hoursL,&minsL);
    print_time(yearsL,dayL,hoursL,minsL);





getchar();

}
```

Comment: What are the outcomes, what are the desired ones, and why do you think they are not correct?

Comment: Your problem may be that you are dealing with 'floats' on an integer-oriented calculation.  There are usually small errors introduced when using floats as a result of imprecise conversion and those errors can seriously magnify when accumulated through multiple operations.  Try making your float-oriented calculations into integers.

Comment: After every fourth year you get an extra day, your floating point number that you use for that might work overall, but not for a specific case, it will always be slightly wrong. You really need to calculate the amount of extra days (year%4) to add.

Comment: Bas van Stein has a good point as well.  Your t_constant has 365.2425 days in a year.  You really need to make that an integer and then make up for it using leap years or your calculation will be correct long-term, but won't line up with the traditional calendar.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I know they are incorrect because im checking them with my pc's time, and the outcomes are constantly changing however theyre about 2 hours in advance and 4 mins

Comment: Convert seconds to days, then days to years using the correct number of days per year. There is an *exact* number of days per year.

Comment: @WeatherVane mmm i see what u mean, but shouldnt the answer be the same as im diving by what i already multiplied?

Comment: Where did you get the number 365.2425? You are using an average number of days per years so the resulting solution is an approximation. If you slightly change the constant the result will change.

Comment: `current_seconds=time(NULL);` is not defined by C to be so.  The value returned from `time()` is commonly the number of seconds sine Jan 1, 1970, but it could be other epochs or other units of time.

Comment: Did you find your solution?

Answer (score 0):

one problem that I see is that you have used only time(). this function does not return time for your time zone. if you need time for your time zone, you need to use localtime() to get correct time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the libraries that are available to you:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/time_h.htm

http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-how-to-use-time-and-date-in-c

from the tutorial linked above:

```
time_t now;
now = time(NULL);     // read the time into 'now'
printf(ctime(&now));  // prints all of the information you are looking for and then some
```

If you don't like the way that time is formatted, use the functions localTime() and strftime():

```
#define DEFAULT_STR_LEN 80
char strNow[DEFAULT_STR_LEN] = {0};

time_t = rawTime;
struct tm *localTime;

time(&rawTime);
localTime = localtime(&rawTime);

strftime(str, DEFAULT_STR_LEN, "%H:%M:%S", localTime);
printf(str);
```

There are lots of % arguments for the strftime() function, take a look around.